# [ag-grid]: Free text filter/ search bar above the grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am new to angular so please accept my apologies if its basic question.
I have a grid defined and it is getting row data from the database. I am trying to place a search bar above the grid to apply an additional free text filter on it. The grid already has column filters on it. Any help would be really appreciated. I am using  Here is my code

```
<input class"search" placeholder="Search..." type="text" ng-model="search-model" ng-change="$ctrl.onFilterChanged(this.search)"/>


onFilterChanged(value){
   this.gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(value);
  }
```

I have also looked into the external filter but I am not able to implement it as a free text. I am really struggling with it. Please help me out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is my final working solution:

In the controller, in `colDef` add a field `getQuickFilterText:<some data renderer function>`

Call it from your HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.gridOptions.quickFilterText" placeholder="Type text to filter..." class="toolbarFilterTextBox"
```

Answer (score 1):

the ng-model that is wrong. The correct value is:

```
<input class"search" placeholder="Search..." type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="$ctrl.onFilterChanged(this.search)"/>
```